# MySQL Wildcard Filtering Special Character using LIKE

Tags: php, mysql

My SQL query is:

```
SELECT * FROM listings  WHERE title LIKE '%Debbie\'s Pet Grooming%'
```

However, when I run this query I get no results. Can you please suggest why. My database table is below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that somehow you have managed to get an actual backslash in the value in the database, so you need to search for that. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM listings  WHERE title LIKE '%Debbie\\\\\'s Pet Grooming%'
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c9441ba040cfbadbd673ec74ad9ffc59)

From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like):

> Because MySQL uses C escape syntax in strings (for example, “\n” to
>   represent a newline character), you must double any “\” that you use
>   in LIKE strings. For example, to search for “\n”, specify it as “\\n”.
>   To search for “\”, specify it as “\\\\”; this is because the
>   backslashes are stripped once by the parser and again when the pattern
>   match is made, leaving a single backslash to be matched against.

Comment: still now not getting result

Comment: @MatiurRahmanMozumdar sorry, not enough backslashes because of the double escaping in strings. See my edit

Comment: this one will also work `select * from tableA where column1 like 'Debbie\\\'s Pet Grooming' ESCAPE '|'`

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
WHERE title LIKE '%Debbie\\\'s Pet Grooming%' ;
```

.

```
SELECT * FROM (
 select  "Debbie\'s Pet Grooming" title
)  t
WHERE title LIKE '%Debbie\\\'s Pet Grooming%' ;
```

but be user you have not space between Debbie and '

The first  \ is for escape the second  and the third  for the single quote

Comment: This is not correct. If you remove your `WHERE` clause, you'll see that the value in `t` does *not* have a backslash in it, which is not the situation that OP is in.